# How to add a column to a pandas DataFrame based on other column values?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Color": ["red", "red", "blue"],
    "Width": ["wide", "narrow", "narrow"],
    "Weight": [12, 12, 12],
})

   Color  Width   Weight
0  red    wide        12
1  red    narrow      12
2  blue   narrow      12
```

I'd like to add a new column `EffWeight`,

```
EffWeight = Weight if Color == 'red' and Width == 'wide' else 0

   Color  Width   Weight  EffWeight
0  red    wide        12         12
1  red    narrow      12          0
2  blue   narrow      12          0
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use a boolean condition and multiply:

```
df['EffWeight'] = (df['Color'].eq('red') & df['Width'].eq('wide')) * df['Weight']
```

another option is to use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
df['EffWeight'] = np.where(df['Color'].eq('red') & df['Width'].eq('wide'), df['Weight'], 0)
```

Output:

```
   Color   Width  Weight  EffWeight
0   red    wide      12         12
1   red  narrow      12          0
2  blue  narrow      12          0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['EffWeight'] = 0
df.loc[(df['Color']=='red') & (df['Width']=='wide'), 'EffWeight'] = df['Weight']
```